# Python- using only the key value with **kwargs

Tags: python-2.7, keyword-argument

I am struggling to figure out how to use **kwargs but also, only use the values from keys from additional arguments that I am using. For example, I have a script that uses an API to submit data for POST requests but on occasion, I may need to hit the endpoint for the API more than once based upon additional arguments that the user provides. Here is what my code looks like:

```
def apiExample(name, location, user, **kwargs):
print name
print location
url = "https://example.com/user?"+str(user)
...
url2 = "https://example2.com/user2?"+str(user2)
...
url3 = "https://example2.com/user3?"+str(user3)
...
```

I would then use the function like this with additional KW arguments provided:

```
apiExample("Bob", "Texas", 45582 , user2=20, user3=5625)
```

I know I am missing something here: what I am trying to accomplish is, I want the ability to use the values provided for my additional user 2 and user 3 function arguments (in this example) as the values for my url2 and url3 statements within my function.

From what I understand the **kwargs, or rather the ** syntax will take all additional keyword arguments I provide and add them to a dictionary so I really don't know how to proceed from here.

There may also be a better way to do this as well!

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need kwargs here at all? Why not not allow passing `users` which is either a single item or a sequence of them, then loop over that?

Comment: Actually I think you are right: I may be making this more complicated than it has to be.